# How to fix NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID on my site while using google chrome on macOS Sierra Version 10.12?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, macos-sierra

When i tried to open my site (https://thaimeditationcenter.com/) by Google Chrome on My mac using macOS Sierra Version 10.12 i got an error like this.

```
Your connection is not private

Attackers might be trying to steal your information from thaimeditationcenter.com 
(for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
Automatically report details of possible security incidents to Google. Privacy policy
```

But when i open it on Firefox , Safari or Google chrome on my Iphone it seems fine there was no error at all.

How can i fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=thaimeditationcenter.com) your site is not configured properly:

> Chain issues  Incomplete

This means that a chain certificates is missing. Some browsers cache chain certificates when visiting other sites and therefore can work around this problem. Other browsers try to download the missing chain certificate. The rest will fail because the trust chain cannot be built.

To fix this you need to add the missing chain certificate to your server configuration. While doing that you should probably also fix all the other problems shown by the SSLLabs report which lead to a bad Grade F for your site.